# STM32 and embedded linux?

Tags: embedded, arm, linux, stm32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux on ARM Cortex-M3 series](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/linux-on-arm-cortex-m3-series)

Friends,

Any ideas on how to use embedded linux into STM32 system ?
Any shares or experiences will be very appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: This topic is dealt with by http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/linux-on-arm-cortex-m3-series