# If a controller has MPU, will it run Linux efficiently?

Tags: linux, cortex-m3

I have an EFM32 board having Cortex M3. This board is having an [Memory Protection Unit](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/EFM32GG990.pdf). Will it be a good idea to port Linux on it? I am discouraged because of this answer:  [Linux on ARM Cortex-M3 series](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/linux-on-arm-cortex-m3-series), especially since I need a fast boot-up and efficiently running OS.

Comment: What do you mean by 'MPU'?

Comment: Its Memory Protection Unit, link added

Comment: Technically Linux needs a MMU, not a MPU.

Comment: How much RAM does your system have? A reasonable minimum for Linux is 64 Mb for a very limited system.

Answer (score 2):

As others have alluded to in the comments of the question, I think what you are actually looking for is an MMU (Memory Management Unit) not an MPU (Memory Protection Unit).  Among other things, a memory management unit is responsible for translating virtual memory addresses to physical memory addresses.

A memory protection unit really just keeps code executing in one mode (typically an unprivileged mode) from clobbering someone else's memory (usually the kernel's memory).  This prevents a user program from bringing down the whole system.

If you are looking for a Unix-like operating system that you can run on hardware without an MMU (like Cortex-M based hardware), you might want to consider NuttX (http://nuttx.org/)